# Binding Observable Collection to multiple wpf trees

Tags: treeview, binding, observablecollection

Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to bind an observable collection to multiple wpf trees using different groupings?  Both bindings are two-way, such that changes in one control should be reflected in both controls.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to modify this sample ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/11/a-treeview-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-a-2d-collection-walk-into-a-bar.aspx ) by adding a secondary grouping and an additional tree.  Grouping by different fields worked well.

I then added a button to add an item with round-robin groupings to the collection and a little snippet to find and select the items in both trees ( social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7e368b93-f509-4cd6-88e7-561e8d3246ae ), and it all works well.

I am still curious to know alternatives.